# JS Object array dynamic join and filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I'm dealing with quite complex situation: I have 3 arrays as show below in JS. The values in the `Values` array keeps on changing every 5 seconds to  either `true` or `false`.

```
var Config = [{
    "rdd": "Transducer Failure",
    "performance": true,
    "agc": false,
    "snr": true,
    "sos": false,
    "flowvel": true
  },
  {
    "rdd": "Detection Problem",
    "performance": false,
    "agc": true,
    "snr": false,
    "sos": true,
    "flowvel": false
  }
]
```

Config array will have configuration for all the instances which all are applicable for respective `rdd`. For example, "Transducer Failure" will have `performance` and `snr` and `flowvel` and not all other fie;dswill be applicable for `agc` and `sos`.

```
var Instance = [{
  "U": [{
    "performance": "abc",
    "agc": "xyz",
    "snr": "pqr",
    "sos": "vns",
    "flowvel": "mns"
  }],
  "Y": [{
    "performance": "a",
    "agc": "b",
    "snr": "c",
    "sos": "d",
    "flowvel": "e"
  }]
}]
```

Instance will have instances with config array:

```
var Values = [{
  "abc": true,
  "xyz": false,
  "pqr": true,
  "vns": false,
  "mns": true,
  "a": true,
  "b": false,
  "c": false,
  "d": true,
  "e": true
}]
```

values will have value with respective to instance value.

I want new object array which match below condition..

1. If value in `Config` is `true`, e.g., if `performance`, `snr` in config array is true, then it maps to respective value in `Instance` array, e.g., if `performance` is `true`, it will be mapped to "abc" in `Instance` array and if `performance` is false it will return NA
2. Value of key in `Config` array will be the value of key in `Values` array. E.g,, if `performance` is `true`, it will be mapped to instance 'abc' and if value of "abc" is `true`, value of `performance` will be `true` or `false`. Secondly, if value of `performance` in `Config` itself is `false`, it will return "NA"

expected output

```
result = [{
  "U": [{
      "rdd": "Transducer Failure",
      "performance": true,
      "agc": "NA",
      "snr": true,
      "sos": "NA",
      "flowvel": true
    },
    {
      "rdd": "Detection Problem",
      "performance": "NA",
      "agc": false,
      "snr": "NA",
      "sos": false,
      "flowvel": "NA"
    }
  ],
  "Y": [{
      "rdd": "Transducer Failure",
      "performance": true,
      "agc": "NA",
      "snr": false,
      "sos": "NA",
      "flowvel": true
    },
    {
      "rdd": "Detection Problem",
      "performance": "NA",
      "agc": false,
      "snr": "NA",
      "sos": true,
      "flowvel": "NA"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. I have used `Object.keys` to get key names and used array notation to assing dynamic names in resulted object key. `Object.assign` is used to get only one object in final result which is resultArray

```js
var Config = [
    {
        "rdd": "Transducer Failure",
        "performance": true,
        "agc": false,
        "snr": true,
        "sos": false,
        "flowvel": true
    },
    {
        "rdd": "Detection Problem",
        "performance": false,
        "agc": true,
        "snr": false,
        "sos": true,
        "flowvel": false
    }
]

var Instance = [{
    "U": [{
        "performance": "abc",
        "agc": "xyz",
        "snr": "pqr",
        "sos": "vns",
        "flowvel": "mns"
    }],
    "Y": [{
        "performance": "a",
        "agc": "b",
        "snr": "c",
        "sos": "d",
        "flowvel": "e"
    }]
}]

var Values = [{
    "abc": true,
    "xyz": false,
    "pqr": true,
    "vns": false,
    "mns": true,
    "a": true,
    "b": false,
    "c": false,
    "d": true,
    "e": true
}]


function getResult(Instance, config, v) {
    let resultArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < Instance.length; i++) {
        const resultKeys = Object.keys(Instance[i])
        const element = Instance[i];
        let prev = null
        resultKeys.forEach((r, index) => {
            let reuslt = {
                [r]: config.map(c => {
                    const configKeys = Object.keys(c)
                    return {
                        [configKeys[0]]: c.rdd,
                        [configKeys[1]]: c[configKeys[1]] ? v[0][element[r][i][configKeys[1]]] : 'NA',
                        [configKeys[2]]: c[configKeys[2]] ? v[0][element[r][i][configKeys[2]]] : 'NA',
                        [configKeys[3]]: c[configKeys[3]] ? v[0][element[r][i][configKeys[3]]] : 'NA',
                        [configKeys[4]]: c[configKeys[4]] ? v[0][element[r][i][configKeys[4]]] : 'NA',
                        [configKeys[5]]: c[configKeys[5]] ? v[0][element[r][i][configKeys[5]]] : 'NA'
                    }
                })
            }
            if (index === 0) {
                prev = reuslt
            }
            else {
                Object.assign(prev, reuslt)
            }
        })
        resultArray.push(prev)
    }
    console.log(resultArray)
}
getResult(Instance, Config, Values)
```